# Want to make specific section on Gutenberg full width

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have this test post: https://allthingsgardener.com/test-ntar-delete-aja/

and i want to make this specific section to be full-width, https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDwlA.jpg

my purpose is to make it like this: https://backlinko.com/conversion-rate-optimization
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBejd.jpg

I want to change the background like that so it'd not be boring to the audiences.

I've tried to put this code in theme customize like this, but its not changing at all except for the background color

```
p.has-background{
    max-width:1290px;
    background-color:blue
    width: 100%!important;
        height: 100%!important;
        background-size: contain!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The property will not fire for the `p` tag, because parent container `.full-width-content .site-inner` sets the width of the block.

To make a full width blocks, you need to change the post template if your theme has one.

Otherwise, you need to reassign the css styles for the parent block.